# GPS connection lost when android app switches to a new screen

Tags: android, gps

I am working on an android app which deals with google map and GPS. Its a proximity alert app that displays the map accepts a touch from the user and sets an alarm for that location. I've added an EditText to accept how far away from the destination would the user like to be notified. But no matter what the user enters, the app is taking that value as 2km. Is it because its using cell tower info instead of GPS? And if there is any tutorial that can help me with developing the app, please share it. When the user selects a location on the map, a new screen will be displayed to let the user enter the notification distance. But the GPS icon disappears when the app goes from the map screen to the user input screen. What could be the problem? This is the part which deals with setting the alarm.

```
    mSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the distance from the shared preferences
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

            String distanceStr = preferences.getString("distance", "0");
            double distance = Double.parseDouble(distanceStr);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(LocationInfoActivity.this,
                MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext().getApplicationContext(), 234324243,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(
                locationManager, preferences, alarmManager,
                pendingIntent);

            if (distance < Double.parseDouble(i)) {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System
                        .currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            } else if (distance < 4.0) {
                WakeMeUtill.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager, 0, 0,
                        locationListener);
            } else {
                double quaterDistance = (distance * 3) / 4;
                WakeMeUtill.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager, 0,
                        (float) quaterDistance * 1000, locationListener);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: which device / Android version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

May be in your code you wrote this line in onPause() method

```
onPause()
{
   gpsLocationManager.removeupdates() 
}
```

please check your code.

if this was not an issue than please share some more detail.